# How to redirect redirect error

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Considering the following shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test > /usr/lib/permDenied 2>&1 > /dev/null 
echo $?
```

This gives me the following error:

```
$ ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 2: /usr/lib/permDenied: Permission denied
1
```

How can I make the error silent and get the error code as well?

Comment: Arfff I tried everything I had in mind but not `echo test 2>/dev/null > /usr/lib/permDenied` ... So frusttrating, I should have known :p!

Comment: This is a duplicate question, I'm sure-- but I'm not looking for it :-)

Comment: shell command line is order dependant! `2>&1 >file` is not equiv than `>file 2>&1` !! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean/16283739#16283739

Answer (score -1):

A search would have found this, but here's an explanation as to why it wasn't working for the future.

`echo test > /usr/lib/permDenied 2>&1 > /dev/null`

```
You first assign STDOUT to a file (STDOUT -> file) 
You then assign STDERR to STDOUT (STDOUT -> file; STDERR -> file) 
You then assign STDOUT to /dev/null (STDOUT ->/dev/null; STDERR -> file)
```

You can't write to the file, so bash's STDERR still goes to STDERR.